# OneLogin java-saml-tookit-jspsample crashes while parsing response

Tags: java, xml, saml-2.0, onelogin

Has anyone tried using the OneLogin Java Toolkit JSP sample successfully?

I have downloaded and tried "java-saml-tookit-jspsample". I was able to follow the instructions and get it setup the Eclipse with JDK8. I was able to configure "onelogin.saml.properties" in the sample and the SAML Test Connector in my OneLogin Account.

When I run the application, I get the login link, and it is able to connect one Login and get back the Authentication response. I can also see the XML received when I debug, but the program crashes while processing the response.

It crashes at following source line in Util.java.

```
docfactory.setAttribute("http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaLanguage", XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
```

With error

> "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaLanguage"

I tried adding a xercesImpl.jar and xml-apis.jar to see if its an XML parser issue, but it did not help either.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of java-saml and I tested it with Oracle Java8 and had no issues.

This [post](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26540121/Deployment-Exception-due-to-xerces-jar.html) suggest that the issue is related with how xerces.jar was installed.